# Automaticly download and update youtube playlist

Tags: youtube-dl

I am using `youtube-dl` to download my music playlist.

Theres only one problem: `youtube-dl` doesn't realize which videos it has already downloaded, so it simply redownloads every single video. I would like it to recongize when new videos have been added and then only redownload those, so that I could run it every 10 seconds or so to check whether or not new videos have been added.

Alternatively I would like a way to download all urls present in a yt playlist, so I can download it and check it against the already downloaded ones, so I can simply runt yt download on those instead.

Basicly I would like a way to get an up to date local copy on my pc of my yt playlist.

Comment: I suggest write script and put all history url at them . Check if link not exist in your txt file start to download

Comment: thats what I wrote. Problem is I don't know how to turn a playlist into a list of video urls or how to tell youtube-dl to not redownload

Comment: use this command : --download-archive archivefile.txt " the option --download-archive FILE youtube-dl both reads and adds to a list of files not to download again. Every time a file is successfully downloaded, that video id is added to file.

Comment: thanks, thats perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `--download-archive archivefile.txt` option.

```
youtube-dl --download-archive FILE
```

`youtube-dl` both reads and adds to a list of files not to download again. Every time a file is successfully downloaded, that video id is added to file.